# Linux Bash for Monthly Archiving

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need help regarding my script on the 1st part is working but when adding more it shows unknown variables lastyear, month

```
#!/bin/bash

year=$(date +%Y)
lastyear=$(expr $year-1) 
month=$(date +%m)
log=$lastyear$month 

mkdir -p /root/temp/$(lastyear) 
mkdir -p /root/temp/$(lastyear)/$(month)

mv -f *$log* $(archivefolder)/$(lastyear)/$(month)
```

Error prompt is

```
./logdate.sh: line 8: lastyear: command not found
./logdate.sh: line 9: lastyear: command not found
./logdate.sh: line 9: month: command not found
```

But When I include only till line 6 it's working

Comment: BTW: of the two `mkdir -p`, the first is superfluous because the `-p` already makes non-existing parents. Or, you can omit the "-p" if you want to check parents in the middle of the process, but then some checking code must be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put the variables in brackets, at the moment the shell is trying to execute the command `lastyear` and put it into a variable. The below should be fine:

```
year=$(date +%Y)
lastyear=$(( year-1 )) 
month=$(date +%m)
log="$lastyear$month"

mkdir -p "/root/temp/$lastyear"
mkdir -p "/root/temp/$lastyear/$month"

mv -f "*$log*" "$archivefolder/$lastyear/$month"
```

Comment: ohh It seems the shell can now see the variables, however the output of the log is = 2017-102 but it should be 201602? Do you have any ideas on this? I already used the expr function for the subtraction

Comment: @mmstores see the edit, you can use `lastyear=$(( year-1 ))` instead

Comment: Thanks @arco444. This really help, now I have to figure out the wildcard of "*201602*"  = OUSDAS-201602xasd, OUTsx121-201602.txt